# RegEx Help, match long string, select substring

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a url, but only want to select part of the url. Is that Possible?

IE: the url would look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/link/88cbdgb7fwndkedl/
```

My Regex looks like so:

```
@"http://www.domain.com/link/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/"
```

and I was hoping to only return the id, but instead its grabbing the whole url.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: using c# Regex.Matches()

Comment: What language? The problem isn't your regex, it's probably just that you're using the whole match instead of the captured group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"http://www.domain.com/link/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/")
string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: so, is `Group[0]` the full match, and `Group[1...etc etc]` successive groups?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all regex solutions allow you to retrieve a group.  You'll find your parenthesized portion waiting for you in group 1.

If you are unable to bother with groups, then you can use positive look-behind:

```
(?<=http://www.domain.com/link/)[^/]+
```

But honestly... try to use groups.  It's a nice feature.  :-)

In C#, it is:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"http://www.domain.com/link/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/");

if (match.Success) {
   string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Match will be the entire url ( what is specified in the regex)

You need to extract the corresponding group.

Something like:

```
foreach(Match m in matches){
m.Groups[1];
}
```